# Why does a target archive behave like a .PHONY target in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefile that builds an archive, `libfoo.a`, from a single object file, `foo.o`, like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
AR=ar

libfoo.a: libfoo.a(foo.o)
foo.o: foo.c
```

The first time I run `make`, it compiles the C file, then creates an archive with the object file:

```
$ make
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar rv libfoo.a foo.o
ar: creating libfoo.a
a - foo.o
```

However, if I run `make` again immediately (without touching `foo.o`), it still tries to update the archive with `ar r` (insert `foo.o` with replacement):

```
$ make
ar rv libfoo.a foo.o
r - foo.o
```

Why does Make do this when it shouldn't have to? (If another target depends on `libfoo.a`, that target will be rebuilt as well, etc.)

According to the output of `make -d`, it seems to be checking for the non-existent file named `libfoo.a(foo.o)`, and apparently decides to rerun `ar r` because of that. But is this supposed to happen? Or am I missing something in my Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this because the people who put together your Linux distribution (in particular the people that built the `ar` program you're using) made a silly decision.

An archive file like `libfoo.a` contains within it a manifest of the object files contained in the archive, along with the time that the object was added to the archive.  That's how `make` can know if the object is out of date with respect to the archive (make works by comparing timestamps, it has no other way to know if a file is out of date).

In recent times it's become all the rage to have "deterministic builds", where after a build is complete you can do a byte-for-byte comparison between it and some previous build, to tell if anything has changed.  When you want to perform deterministic builds it's obviously a non-starter to have your build outputs (like archive files) contain timestamps since these will never be the same.

So, the GNU binutils folks added a new option to `ar`, the `-D` option, to enable a "deterministic mode" where a timestamp of `0` is always put into the archive so that file comparisons will succeed.  Obviously, doing this will break make's handling of archives since it will always assume the object is out of date.

That's all fine: if you want deterministic builds you add that extra `-D` option to `ar`, and you can't use the archive feature in `make`, and that's just the way it is.

But unfortunately, it went further than that.  The GNU binutils developers unwisely (IMO) provided a configuration parameter that allowed the "deterministic mode" to be specified as the *default* mode, instead of requiring it to be specified via an extra flag.

Then the maintainers of some Linux distros made an even bigger mistake, by adding that configuration option when they built binutils for their distributions.

You are apparently the victim of one of these incorrect Linux distributions and that's why make's archive management doesn't work for your distribution.

You can fix it by adding the `-U` option, to force timestamps to be used in your archives, when you invoke `ar`:

```
ARFLAGS += -U
```

Or, you could get your Linux distribution to undo this bad mistake and remove that special configuration parameter from their binutils build.  Or you could use a different distribution that doesn't have this mistake.

I have no problem with deterministic builds, I think they're a great thing.  But it loses features and so it should be an *opt-in* capability, not an on-by-default capability.